# How to prevent a Nixpkgs overlay from being applied more than once?

Tags: inheritance, nix, diamond-problem, fixpoint-combinators, nixpkgs

Suppose I have some Nixpkgs overlays composed from other overlays:

```hs
overlayFoo = self: super: {
  # ...
};
overlayBar = pkgs.lib.fixedPoints.composeExtensions overlayFoo (self: super: {
  # ...
};
overlayBaz = pkgs.lib.fixedPoints.composeExtensions overlayFoo (self: super: {
  # ...
});
```

And the user of the overlays would like to use them like this:

```hs
pkgs = import nixpkgs {
  inherit system;
  overlays = [overlayBar overlayBaz];
};
```

Since both `overlayBar` and `overlayBaz` depend on `overlayFoo`, how can I prevent `overlayFoo` from being applied more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-to-prevent-a-overlay-from-being-applied-more-than-once/27312/2?u=atry

> You could add a marker to nixpkgs to check if the overlay has been applied already:

```hs
overlayFoo = self: super: self.lib.optionalAttrs (!super.__fooHasBeenApplied or false) {
  __fooHasBeenApplied = true;
  # ...
};
```